# JW Player not showing up for internet explorer users

Tags: internet-explorer, web, video-streaming, jwplayer

I'm trying to include some videos on a website I help to maintain using JW Player, and some internet explorer users are reporting that they don't see the video box show up at all (i.e. the space where the video player should be is completely blank, not displaying an error about flash version or anything like that).

Here is the code that I'm using to initialize the video player:

```
    <div id='player_5465'></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("player_5465").setup({
    file: "http://bmt.umn.edu/video/Bench-to-bedside Jakubtolar 480x270.mp4",
    width: "480px",
    height: "270px",
    image: "http://bmt.umn.edu/video/tolar-b2b-screenshot.png",
    });
    </script>
    </div>
```

When I try to test this with IE7 (I'm using software called IETester) it gives me a script error and asks if I want to keep running scripts on the page. I say yes, but then I don't see a video box at all.

The video should be viewable at the bottom of http://bmt.umn.edu/why-choose-us/collaboration-towards-new-treatments.php#Tolar-bench-to-bedside

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

John

Comment: I tried removing the comma at the end of the "image:" line per http://craigsworks.com/projects/forums/showthread.php?tid=1930, and now instead of the error in IE7 being "Expected identifier, string or number" it is "Invalid argument". The video continues to work fine in chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I figured it out. I upgraded to 6.5 per Ethan's suggestions, but that alone did not fix the problem. Looking at the instructions on http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28839/embedding-the-player/ section 2, it appears that the height and width should not be enclosed in quotes or have the letters px after them. The following code is now working for me:

```
<div id="player_5465"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jwplayer("player_5465").setup({
        file: "http://bmt.umn.edu/video/b2b-jakub-tolar.mp4",
        width: 480,
        height: 270,
        image: "http://bmt.umn.edu/video/tolar-b2b-screenshot.png"
     });
     </script>
</div>
```

Comment: If the width or height is specified using "%" then it throws error so if height or width is in "%" then add quotes around it.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to removing the comma on the last line, I would also update your player from 6.2 to 6.5 - http://account.longtailvideo.com/