# Internet Explorer, upload scripts via the DoubleClick for Publishers

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jwplayer

only Internet Explorer show following message:

**"jwplayer" is undefiniert**

after translation:

**The value of property "$" is null or undefined, no Function object**

Original: *Der Wert der Eigenschaft "$" ist Null oder undefiniert, kein Function-Objekt*

The Story.
About the DoubleClick for Publishers(DFP) video advertising is delivered.
In the DFP Video advertising has its own template.
looks something like this:

```
<script src="//www.paht_to_jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<div class="ad mediumrectangle">
<div class="ad-inner">
    <small>Advertising </small>
    <div class="ad-container" align="center">
        <div id="myElement">Loading the player...</div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//paht_to_jwpalyer/jwplayer.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">jwplayer.key="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"</script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
           jwplayer("myElement").setup({
                       width : '620',
                       height: '465',
                       file  : '[%VideoLink%]',
                       image : '[%PreviewLink%]',
                       primary: 'flash',
                        ga: { trackingobject: "ga" }
           });
           jwplayer("myElement").onPlay(function(event) {
                if(event.oldstate != "PAUSED")
                {
                    var xmlHttp = null;
                    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xmlHttp.open( "GET", "%%CLICK_URL_UNESC%%" , false );
                    xmlHttp.send( null );
                }
           });
        });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

As I said, with the exception of IE other browsers are working without problems.

The links "Vidoe Link" and "Preview Link" refer to one of our servers where the video with the preview image is.
I realize that when the page loads the JWplayer variable **jwplayer** is not loaded by the IE or later!
For whatever reason.
Does anyone have a suggestion on how to fix it?

greetings

Comment: as posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18067944/jw-player-not-showing-up-for-internet-explorer-users try removing the quotes around the width and height, maybe it's the same issue.

Comment: No, unfortunately it has not helped

Comment: Hmm, does this part work in non-ie browsers? jwplayer.key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" I've never worked with jwplayer, so this part seems weird to me, that you can assign the key directly after calling the script.

Comment: The key is just an example, without the key the JWplayer logo appears, this variable should therefore play no role.

Comment: I fear I've ran out of ideas about what could be wrong. Good luck finding the bug.

Comment: Do you have a link you can provide?

Comment: Hi,
the solution in my case was change the document typ:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">`